# Did Ratchet die in "Age of Extinction"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

Did Ratchet die in *Age of Extinction*? I know that he was seen briefly in the movie, but was he killed by a Decepticon off-screen?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBX45K2BiSs?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Age_of_Extinction#Plot), [Ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Age_of_Extinction#Voices) is killed by Lockdown on-screen in *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, because he refuses to tell Lockdown where Optimus Prime is.

Comment: thank you Paul D. Waite

Comment: @JoshuaCornish: no worries fella.

Comment: @JoshuaCornish If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the green tick mark next to it. It'll inform other users that your query has been answered, and both you and Paul will earn some extra reputation from it.

Comment: is it the red flag

Comment: We’ve only just told the poor chap that Wikipedia exists, we can leave the details of Stack Exchange’s reputation system for later!